# One hot encode list of vectors

Tags: r, tidyverse

Is there a quick way to one-hot encode lists of vectors (with different lenghts) in R, preferably using tidyverse?

For example:

```
vals <- list(a=c(1), b=c(2,3), c=c(1,2))
```

The wanted result is a wide dataframe:

```
   1   2   3
a  1   0   0
b  0   1   1
c  1   1   0
```

Thanks!

Comment: this is a list of vectors not a list of lists

Comment: Yep. I fixed it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can `enframe` the list and convert them into separate rows, create a dummy column and convert the data into wide-format using `pivot_wider`.

```
library(tidyverse)

enframe(vals) %>%
  unnest(value) %>%
  mutate(temp = 1) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value, values_from = temp, values_fill = list(temp = 0))

#  name    `1`   `2`   `3`
#  <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1 a         1     0     0
#2 b         0     1     1
#3 c         1     1     0
```

Answer (score 3):

One `base R` option could be:

```
t(table(stack(vals)))

   values
ind 1 2 3
  a 1 0 0
  b 0 1 1
  c 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 0):

A base R approach,

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(vals, function(i) as.integer(!is.na(match(unique(unlist(vals)), i)))))

#  [,1] [,2] [,3]
#a    1    0    0
#b    0    1    1
#c    1    1    0
```